# How can I remove parent element when its child is clicked

Tags: jquery

how can i remove an ul if I click one of its children which is inside of it ? 
I know this ul .remove not true and How can I set color of "projects" as red?
I have to use .find()

```
<ul class="w1m">
    <li>
       <div>
         <img src="img/minus.png" onclick="$(this ul).remove();"/>
         <img src="img/link.png"/>
       </div>
       <div>
         inspiration
       </div>
    </li> 
</ul>

<ul class="w1m">
    <li>
       <div>
         <img src="img/minus.png" onclick="$(this ul).remove();"/>
         <img src="img/link.png"/>
       </div>
       <div>
         projects
       </div>
    </li> 
<ul>
    <li><div><img src="img/minus.png"/><img src="img/link.png"/></div>  <div>job board website</div></li>
    <li><div><img src="img/minus.png"/><img src="img/link.png"/></div>  <div>shopping cart</div></li>
</ul></ul>
```

Comment: $(this).parent('ul').remove();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).closest("ul").remove();
```

Or better yet:

```
$("ul.w1m").on("click","img[src='img/minus.png']",function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: $(this).parent('ul').remove(); doesnt work,  $(this).closest("ul").remove(); OK!!!

Comment: @GüneşErdemi I never suggested `$(this).parent('ul').remove();`. What's your point?

Comment: How can I set color of "projects" as red? I have to use .find()

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$(this).closest('ul').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

using the following Jquery for that

```
$(this).closest("ul").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all, the way you are adding the handler is not ideal.  at the bottom of your page, in a script tag, you should add this code inside of jQuery's ready method.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('ul.w1m > li').on('click', function() { $(this).parent().remove(); });

  });
</script>
```

in your above code, the value of `this` would be the `<img>` element, and you would be trying to select the *child* ul of that img (which obviously doesn't exist).  Also, when using the `this` keyword with other selectors in jQuery, you need to wrap the other selectors in quotes.  (ie `$(this+'ul')`).

Comment: thanks Madlee, How can I set color of "projects" word as red? I have to use .find()

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
})
```